# Integrate Salesforce to web form to capture data

Tags: api, form, sales-cloud

We are currently using a form on our website to capture information from subscribers such as email, first name, last name (and send them a follow up "welcome" email). 
From now, we would like to get the data captured directly into SFDC (and Marketing Cloud via the connector).

What is the best way to proceed?

We've been struggling to get the right information with our agency and to work this through APIs. Especially getting a API endpoint to post on it.

Thank you very much for your help.

AP

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use an app exchange package like Formatica (I think that's the name) and have it create your form which is then brought in using Web to Lead. In general, the easiest way to do this is using Web To Lead and process the form using routing rules accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. So you recommend to create a new form instead of using our exisiting one?

Comment: @Aurelien That's entirely up to you. The fields on your existing form will need to exist in your web to lead is what's important. You can style your form in any manner you want to. At a minimum, you'll need to update the existing form so it's fields and form Id are recognized by Web to Lead.